# How to change image position in itunes connect metadata?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

By mistake, during my last update of my ios app, i have switched the order of the first two images i provided for the iphone version. Now (the app has been approved) i want to change the image position, but it seems to me i can't change it. When i use "Edit" on the right metadata window, i can drag images but then they go back where they were, changing nothing.
It's important for the first image is used by the app store: when someone search my app, he see a wrong image that it's not the one i want to present the app.
I need to add a new version, upload binary and wait a week for the review in order to change the position of the images??

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. Stackoverflow is also for `software tools commonly used by programmers` [faq]

Comment: James Webster, itunes connects isn't a software tool

Comment: You can't unless you upload a new version of your app

Comment: yes, it is. It has a different use, that is part of developing if you want to publish on the app store. Furthermore, there's plenty of questions here about itunes connect. I don't believe to be the first, am i?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason which for i continued finding discordant opinion about this matter. Before january 2013 it was possible to do it, then Apple decided that this was something to mantain locked while the app is in state of "Ready for sale".
Here's a documentation file pointing out what is locked and what not.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1

To change image position, unfortunately, it is necessary to prepare a new version and upload a new binary.